# What Easter eggs do we have on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, support, fun, easter-eggs

I would like to know what Easter eggs are hiding in Stack Overflow, and all the other Stack Exchange sites.

I love Easter eggs and I love Stack Overflow, so adding even more is a good idea in my opinion, what do you think?

Answer (score 23):

> Ok I just found my favorite one, head over to
> https://stackexchange.com/about/team -> some images have roll-overs
> with animated gif's.

**They are hilarious!**

Editor note: the above link is broken, the company decided to remove that page. However, most animations have been preserved in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264229/152859). (Execute the code block there  to see.)

Comment: Most team members have those animations by now - thanks for finding this! :)

Comment: ZOMG Michael Pryor's is the best EVER!!!!! what a legend.

Comment: I have a semi-serious quesiton (I KNOW THIS IS A COMMENT) can we add Jeff's photo to this link - http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=GEEK

Answer (score 22):

I think that the 404, `/error` and `/captcha` pages are already Easter Eggs of some sort.

Links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/404
- https://serverfault.com/404
- https://superuser.com/404
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/404
- https://stackoverflow.com/error
- https://serverfault.com/error
- https://superuser.com/error
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/error
- https://stackoverflow.com/captcha
- https://serverfault.com/captcha
- https://superuser.com/captcha
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/captcha

Comment: HaHaHa that last captcha link is funny, it changes occasionally but here is [today's](http://www.jinx.com/men/shirts/video_games/humans_are_dead.html)

Answer (score 21):

One easter egg coming up:

[image: Binary Easter Egg]

Comment: Nice. Took me second to figure it out.

Comment: For those who care, it says "Easter Egg" :)

Comment: Actually, it says "easter egg" (no caps)

Answer (score 13):

Here's what you might call an easter egg:

If you go to any sample newsletter, e.g. https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=stackoverflow.com, some of the links at the bottom will lead you to ... let's say, quite peculiar YouTube videos, if I may make that judgment that without having watched them all the way until the end:

> [Unsubscribe from this newsletter](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHy7DGLTt8g) or change your email preferences by visiting your [subscriptions page on stackexchange.com](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZZ7oFKsKzY).
>
> Questions? Comments? Let us know on our [feedback site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). If you no longer want to receive mail from Stack Exchange, [unsubscribe from all stackexchange.com emails](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkfVdrtLcRs).

---

As of sometime between now and when this was originally posted, the link above was removed from YouTube. [Here's the new, correct link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6LzEbuI7e8) from the current newsletter page for your enjoyment.

Comment: The unsubscribe link going to Trolololo is actually rather...evil

Comment: You didn't watch them all to the end??? You *gotta* watch them all to the end! Otherwise, you'll never know how to unsubscribe...

Answer (score 5):

Maybe there are... they just haven't been found? Isn't that the whole point of an easter egg?

Comment: Maybe he feels sharing is caring?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to hide easter-eggs in user posts by using HTML comments. Like in [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/356774/edit). I wonder if it is possible to search Stack Exchange for those...

Comment: Well that's more of a less-known feature of markdown, but think it can fit here as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I once tried to open https://stackoverflow.com/wp-admin and https://stackoverflow.com/wp-login to see what happens.

I noticed they redirect you to a random 3 hour completely dummy video on youtube. But I think it's not working now. Too bad :(

That was hilarious

Comment: That wasn't meant as an Easter Egg. It was to frustrate bots and script kiddies. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330161/812149) for some details.