# Would like to see more employee animations

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, stack-exchange-team

> **There was a recent change in the design of the team page, removing all animations.
> This request has become irrelevant due to this. Thanks for all the supporters!**

---

In the [team page](https://stackexchange.com/about/team), 40 employees got a cool animation, e.g. [Geoff animation](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/team/Geoff%20Dalgas.gif).

However, looks like no new animations were created for a long long time - is it possible to add animation for some of the new recruits?

[image]

Comment: Step 1. Grab screen Step 2. Shake

Comment: What is this team page you speak of? Link?

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/about/team

Comment: The employee formerly in charge of animations is no longer with us :(

Comment: @Oded oh my! And nobody can replace him/her? I see "graphic design by Sean Gallagher" - can't Sean do animations? :)

Comment: Thank you for volunteering @Oded. ;-) That said, its a series of stills that are sized appropriately and combined into an animated gif (with a tool such as http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/ ).

Comment: @MichaelT but someone have to take those pictures... maybe the retired employee wasn't designer like I was thinking but rather responsible to take those pictures. :(

Comment: Hah! Chris Jaeger, Tonberry!

Comment: @danielhanly.com no! It's a cactuar and [I spotted it first](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137664/152859)! :-)

Comment: Shhh.. that's what I meant! It's been so long since I played FF.

Comment: @danielhanly.com FF8 you mean... FF12 isn't so old just yet.

Comment: The latest ones are not as good as they used to be! I haven't played for some time. 10 was the last good one.

Comment: @danielhanly.com agreed. Squall was the best ever.

Comment: +1 for applying [status-declined] to your own feature-request :)

Comment: @Hacker not really declined, more like [tag:status-cannot-really-do-that-anymore-even-if-we-really-want-to]. ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard your link takes me nowhere... what r u pointing to?

Comment: @Hack what link? Just checked both links (team page and Geoff animation) and they both work fine. What did I miss?

Comment: the above comment "like status-cannot-really-do-that-anymore-even-if-we-really-want-to" link broken

Comment: @Hack umm, that was just a joke. It's a tag that does not exist. You can put any tag you like, and even if doesn't exist, get such a page.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I missed the ;-) again

Comment: If we want to preserve information in this thread, maybe it shouldn't be nominated  for deletion? In the present state, the whole thing will be deleted whenever three 10K decide to do so for whatever reason. I think it would be better to edit the question to something along the lines of "would like to _still_ see the animations" -- which is what the answer provides.

Answer (score 11):

Before it's closed, I wanted to stash all the past animations but alas, they changed the whole source to some dynamic picture creator and archive.org is borked when it comes to jQuery.

I was able to salvage some via Google, if anyone can find more please add them as well. Thanks!

*Since it's going to be lots of animations, wrapping it as code - just click "Run code snippet" to  see all of them*.

```html
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/463168/abby-hairboat"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/80Abh.gif" title="Abby Miller" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/328700/"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm65t.gif" title="Alex Miller" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/37099"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqDVV.gif" title="Adam Lear" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/1306193"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/otsB5.gif" title="Ben Kiziltug" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/40051/balpha"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZPuD.gif" title="Ben Dumke-von der Ehe" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/1266634/bethany"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OLe4.gif" title="Bethany Marzewski" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/welcome-valued-associates-anna-rachel-carleejean-and-charles/"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKnMr.gif" title="Charles Bernoskie" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/102159/grace-note"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/erUMk.gif" title="Chris Jaeger" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/1285330"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibiwo.gif" title="Dammand Cherry" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/32917/david-fullerton"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxqUc.gif" title="David Fullerton" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D2OC.gif" title="Geoff Dalgas" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/353675"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKEb3.gif" title="Greg Drinkwater" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/383041"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVVRq.gif" title="Guy Zerega" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpXnR.gif" title="Jarrod Dixon" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/4188/jason-punyon"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXQ7Z.gif" title="Jason Punyon" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553/tall-jeff"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xyhb.gif" title="Jeff Szczepanski" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN4l0.gif" title="Joel Spolsky" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/620"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1JTS.gif" title="Josh Heyer" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/29738/kevin-montrose"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/05j4t.gif" title="Kevin Montrose" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/77247/korneel-bouman"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCJEe.gif" title="Korneel Bouman" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/37483/kyle-brandt"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox3iw.gif" title="Kyle Brandt" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/463263/laura"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhVCE.gif" title="Laura Dobrzynski-Gessner" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/11975/marc-gravell"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/unpZ4.gif" title="Marc Gravell" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/26961/matt-sherman"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY5xA.gif" title="Matt Sherman" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/237721"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8PA8.gif" title="Nick Cardillo" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver?tab=topactivity"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLrxp.gif" title="Nick Craver" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/59521/nicklarsen"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CJIL.gif" title="Nick Larsen" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/490194/peter-grace"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1BOQ.gif" title="Peter Grace" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/921641/hammer"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8XDA.gif" title="Rachel Boyman" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/34933/robert-cartaino"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/60QeM.gif" title="Robert Cartaino" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/482412/samthebrand"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KU7J.gif" title="Sam Brand" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/2433791/stefan-schwarzgruber"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3giq.gif" title="Stefan Schwarzgruber" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/1246026/stevvve"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq8OO.gif" title="Steve Feldman" /></a>
</div>
<div class="animation">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/1345480/will-cole"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHi6V.gif" title="Will Cole" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I got all except Pops aka Kevin Chang. Alphabetized by first name, since we're all friends... right?

Comment: @NormalHuman awesome! How did you find all of these?

Comment: The filenames are "First Last.gif", for example `http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/team/Abby%20Miller.gif` Don't know why "Kevin Chang" doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, but how you know who had animation? That's what blocked me.

Comment: I tried all of them to be sure.

Comment: @Norm wow, very dedicated to the cause! Unless you used some script? :-)

Comment: @Norm found the old page hiding in [SE dev environment](http://dev.stackexchange.com/about/team)! It's proving Kevin Chang never had animation, Will Cole is the last one to have animation.

Comment: Still thinking that Grace one should include the text "1000 Needles" somewhere

Comment: @SPArcheon well feel free to add and upload the new version. ;-)