# Easter Eggs on StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, fun, easter-eggs

I've been on StackOverflow for sometime now and haven't found any Easter Eggs. If you aren't familiar with what an "Easter Egg" is in this context, here is how [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)) defines it: An Easter egg is an intentional joke, hidden message, or feature in a work.

Anyway after some research, I found a pretty funny one on the Stack Exchange About page [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16717/easter-eggs-in-so-su-sf). Stack Exchange is a pretty robust network and I know that google and youtube are chock-full of these things, so I'd expect Stack Overflow to have a few.

Know about any that are funny/cool? Have any personal favorites?

**Edit:** Chat has some Easter eggs that you can find in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75861/what-easter-eggs-do-the-chat-sites-have) question.

Comment: If I knew where any were, they wouldn't be easter eggs, would they?

Comment: Two words: Konami Code

Comment: [Chat has some.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75861/what-easter-eggs-do-the-chat-sites-have)

Comment: There's one [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16719/216322)

Comment: It is possible to attach invisible content to posts using `<!-- HTML comments. -->`. I wouldn't be surprised, if some user-posts contain easter-eggs through that. Doesn't work in comments.