# What is.... the Chicken? 

Tags: support, chat, fun, winter-bash-2017, chicken

**Update:**

> Continue to [🐔 The Quest for the Winter Chicken of the Bash, Part 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304391/the-quest-for-the-winter-chicken-of-the-bash-part-2)

---

Clues will be updated here too

---

So, we just noticed a [new, fowl user on the tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6548329#6548329)

[image: Icon of rooster]

I think he called  us chicken. Or called itself a chicken. Or something poultry like that.

[image: Screenshot of the Chicken chat user]

And interestingly it's a  system user. (i.e. with negative ID)

So... what's the story? Who knows what fowlness lurks in the heart of the chicken?

---

And a few hours later, while I was asleep, or at least away from my PC (It happens!)

[image: screenshot of chicken chat user. Chicken emoji egg emoji]

She laid an egg? The plot *chickens*

<sub>I do not mean to presume, but a rooster laying a egg would probably mean a [cockatrice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockatrice)?</sub>

---

And, it's hatched:

[image: screenshot of chicken user, hatched egg emoji, chicken emoji]

Still no closer to the truth.

---

A few hours later... a wild chick appears!

[image: chick emoji, chicken emoji]

(what next?)

---

Bulk chicken update. (cause a bunch of stuff happened overnight ;p)

[image]

Looks like the chick became a chicken,  the chicken went away, suffered from empty nest syndrome..

And Chicken and a hat! It could be a winterbash thing.

---

[image]
Chicken Update. Looks a little like the winterbash banner?

---

Saw a rooster wandering around my neighbourhood. Declined to comment.

---

[Another day another clue](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6562525#6562525)

### [image]

[And another clue!](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6566450#6566450)

[image]

The country was identified by [gparyani as Namibia, which has ISO code of "NA"](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6566496#6566496), and [AndrewT recognised the odd symbol as a "Ko"](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6566552#6566552)

57.1% (four sevenths) of "Namibia" is "Nami", so Ko-Nami?

Maybe it's to do with the 57.1 percent and the grey and purple?

---

[Catija did the Konami Code to the Chicken](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6566634#6566634) and was responded with <s>another chicken</s> the turtles?

[image: TMNT]

Mystery Solved.

[image]

SPArchaeologist managed to figure out what it was.

Comment: That user was created today.

Comment: Calling it: new Hairboat styled hat. To avoid having a random lucky employee to win a free pings Epic Loot Box they have created a dedicated spam receiver account. Probably related to the turkey hat if that is getting implemented as someone suggested..

Comment: @Derpy except... you can *not* ping it :/

Comment: @AndrewT. and that is totally expected. If they have some of the winter bash scripts already running for test they will want to avoid someone to ping the chicken and getting the hat BEFORE the event starts.

Comment: Who's going to try seeing if superpinging it works :p

Comment: I can't! My diamond! IT DOES NOTHING HERE!

Comment: @JourneymanGeek but you got plenty of system users on the global SE chat... ;)

Comment: I suspect fowl play is involved... :)

Comment: The chicken returned... https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6549835#6549835

Comment: I wouldn't egg it on if I were you...

Comment: Somehow its chat profile says it has posted zero lifetime chat messages, whereas at the time it made the messages it said two lifetime messages.

Comment: @gparyani that's the case for all system chat users, same way Community profile page is showing false information (e.g. no views). Probably there's no ordinary record for those in the Users table.

Comment: You should totally drop the chicken and try jQuery.

Comment: Easter eggs for Winterbash? Did somebody at SO get their holidays mixed up? :-)

Comment: Somebody rescue the chicken! If it is mixed up in the Winter Bash it will become Kentucky Frozen Chicken!

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2aJb.gif Looks like they didn't need to use the last hint.

Comment: This HAS to be a thing again next year!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since Journeyman asked, I will cross-reference this here.

Remember the Konami code hint and the TMNT picture?

Well, it turns out that:

> Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles III: The Manhattan Project (NES) – Entering the code at the turtle-select screen with the A and B buttons reversed gives access to a stage select/option mode and is the only way to change the options in the game; otherwise, the player will start on normal difficulty with three spare lives.

(source: Wikipedia)

So, basically. Every. Year. I. Try. The. Konami. Code. On. The. Winter. Bash. Site.
And yet, they managed to still troll me, by reversing the BA sequence.

The actual code to enter on the Winter Bash site is:

> up, up, down, down, left, right, left, right, A, B

And.. this is the result.

[image]

A question still lingers. Is this the full story? I will update this post if anything new is discovered.

In the meantime, my loyal subject, go and see for yourself. And bring some bird feed too.

Comment: Uhm, yes, this was totally for... trolling... and totally not because I misremembered the Konami code and then had to use the Turtles to direct you towards the A-B-reversed version... definitely not that.

Comment: Why, of course not. Considering I tried it a few times this morning ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I don't know what you tried, but the A-B version has worked from the start.

Comment: The BA version ._. Cause I didn't think of varients. Never been much of a console gamer

Comment: @balpha at least your error did something good: you got to post clues for longer. If you used the correct version, I would have posted about the chicken on day 1 since that is the first thing I do every year.

Comment: basically, next year just add an alert("Sorry, SPArchaeologist, no chicken this year")

Comment: @balpha You did a good job at hiding the JS. Or I did a bad job when looking at the code.

Comment: @Stijn I did my best ;)

Answer (score 14):

It is a '[Feed User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238453/the-automated-stack-exchange-feeds-user-is-now-participating-in-chat/238617#comment781989_238617)' (a Chicken Feed?). It might respond or just hang out (depending upon what occurs in interstitial space).

A great relief, as it could have been [this](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/79674/what-is-this-colored-fiber-in-my-chicken) .

Until its operation is publicly disclosed we can only speculate what it does. Probably it has a purpose; it's unlikely simply to be the [source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16717/easter-eggs-in-so-su-sf) of [Easter eggs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75861/what-easter-eggs-do-the-chat-sites-have).

Shog9 is [asked about The Chicken](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41679767#41679767).

There are questions below asking if the chicken is related to the [Winterbash](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/12/12/winter-bash-2017-greatest-hits-hats/?cb=1). There is no mention on that blog.

I found a hat that 'just works' (on every site), it's a secret.
Didn't see any chickens to obtain the hat.

December 14, 2017 Update: Another secret hat, don't know why; but it's nicer than the last because I can see better and it suits my avatar.

Left and came back 4 hours later, another secret hat; I didn't see any chickens while offline.

December 26, 2017 Update: This is [how to obtain specific hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304340/winter-bash-2017-hats), not a peep about chickens.

Comment: Meaning that annoying conversation-interrupter is back? Can we shove him into the [coop](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1134/chicken-coop-on-the-meta)?

Comment: Oh that its a feed user is clear. What is it actually doing tho?

Comment: The feet are a lie.

Comment: @Catija - Thanks for the tip, edited out that sentence.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek if we didn't get real reply so far, most likely we won't get any... :(

Comment: ehh. Patience is nice. Also vaguely sanctioned fun.

Comment: also, if its a winterbash thing, not yet?

Comment: Yeah, probably related to Winterbash, though no idea how. :) @JourneymanGeek