# Winter Bash 2018 Hat list

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, secret-hats, winter-bash-2018

Here we go again, the Winter Bash is here and the hats are listed below.

The list has the same format as always, there are only two answers: one for the secret hats, and one for the regular hats. The secret hat list will be updated as we learn them.

*Only edit the secret hat answer with **definitive and correct triggers**. This is not the place to post guesses.*

If you'd like to discuss Winter Bash, hats or just have a question about it please come over to the [Winter Bash c*hat* room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86686/winter-bash-2018-edition).

Keep the comments clean. As always comments are not meant for extended discussion, conversation, "I just got hat X", etc use the [c*hat* room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86686/winter-bash-2018-edition) for that.
I know you are excited you just got a secret hat, but please instead of posting a comment come over to the [c*hat* room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86686/winter-bash-2018-edition) and tell us there.

Comment: How do we determine definitive triggers when it takes like 30 minutes for hats to update?!

Comment: @NH. trial and error, mainly, looking for users with low activity etc.

Comment: Thus far **[27 different hats](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe#winter-bash)** have been discovered. AlecXE is one of the leaders, his hat rack ***might*** update with the list of the most hats, otherwise check Panda's or other top user here [https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network).

Answer (score 163):

## Secret hats for Winter Bash 2018

*Click on each of the hats for a larger image.*

---

#### Retro Fan

[image: Retro Fan]

> Vote on a post (question or answer) more than 1 year old.
>
> Discussed and tested in this [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86686/conversation/retro-fan).

---

#### The Merlin

[image: The Merlin]

> Earn an [Enlightened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/19/enlightened) badge.

---

#### James Bond

[image: James Bond]

> Post an answer scoring at least +7 with 0 comments on the question and 0 comments on the answer.

---

#### Waffles<sup>1</sup>

[image: Waffles]

> Post 15 comments in a single UTC day.
>
> Trigger confirmed by Catija [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48363606#48363606).

---

#### Rubber Ducky

[image: Rubber Ducky]

> Use the discard button on any ["Ask A Question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page. It can take as much as 3 hours to get.
>
> Alternatively, start a draft and wait 7 days for it to be self-deleted.
>
> Trigger confirmed by Catija [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48364417#48364417).

---

#### Sun Wukong

[image: Sun Wukong]

> Write a post on a Meta site (MSE is considered a meta site too) that receives at least 5 up votes and 5 down votes.
>
> Suggested with these criteria by hat [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305500/suggestions-for-winter-bash-2018/305506#305506).
>
> The same hat and trigger was also used [in 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271127).

---

#### Clean-Up Duty<sup>1</sup>

[image: Clean-Up Duty]

> Edit 5 questions that later get upvoted.
>
> Trigger confirmed by Catija [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48363606#48363606).

---

#### Propel Thyself

[image: Propel Thyself]

> Get three other secret hats on one site.
>
> Discussed and tested in this [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86686/conversation/propel-thyself-test).

---

#### Eliza Doolots<sup>1</sup>

[image: Eliza Doolots]

> Earn 2019 rep across the network, excluding association bonus. Hat is awarded on sites where you earn 200+ rep.
>
> Hat suggested by Catija [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304644/358161) and trigger confirmed by Catija [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48358938#48358938).

---

<sup>1</sup>Trigger revealed after Winter Bash has ended.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304340/winter-bash-2017-hats

Comment: Will the rest of the secret hats remain secret forever?

Comment: Probably not. The remaining triggers will be revealed in the wrap-up blog post (or so I expect).

Comment: @Glorfindel [nope](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48341777#48341777) :(

Comment: @WELZ Catija revealed one (Eliza). Maybe they will tell us more if we <s>annoy</s>ask them enough.

Comment: We want to know the real triggers!!!!!!

Comment: **About "Clean-Up Duty" hat is absolutelly wrong information!** And **[here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377912/9801830)** we have the correct answer.

Comment: @Bharata you're really saying that the SE employees who designed the hat would have the wrong information?

Answer (score 87):

## Common hats for Winter Bash 2018

*Click on each of the hats for a larger image.*

---

#### Scarf Ace

[image: Scarf Ace]

earn the [Guru badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/18/guru)

---

#### Glasses With A Number On Top

[image: Glasses With A Number On Top]

starred chat, ±12h from Jan 1, 0:00 UTC

---

#### It Ain’t Easy Being Cheesy

[image: It Ain’t Easy Being Cheesy]

wear 6 hats, changing hats here in 6 days

proposed by [Edlothiad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304605/278094)

---

#### Six-Cornered Hat

[image: Six-Cornered Hat]

earn the [Necromancer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer)

proposed by [Brian](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304577/278094)

---

#### Peacekeeper

[image: Peacekeeper]

20 reviews, no fails

---

#### Rep Hunter

[image: Rep Hunter]

5 accepted answers in 1 day

proposed by [Cai](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304785/278094)

---

#### Pizza Hat

[image: Pizza Hat]

answer +3 a question with accepted answer

---

#### Red Baron

[image: Red Baron]

answer question at -3, becomes +3 and answer +5

---

#### Brunhilde

[image: Brunhilde]

earn 150 rep on three non-SO sites in 15 days

---

#### SO Goes Flapper

[image: SO Goes Flapper]

short answer accepted over long answer

proposed by [rumtscho](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304687/278094)

---

#### Team Player

[image: Team Player]

visit [stackoverflow.com/teams](http://stackoverflow.com/teams)

---

#### It’s-a me!

[image: It’s-a me!]

delete 6 comments after owner edits post

---

#### Still Fresh

[image: Still Fresh]

new user, less than 6 months old, earn 25 rep (The association bonus counts towards the rep requirement.)

proposed by [hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304625/278094)

---

#### IDENTIFICATION DIVISION

[image: IDENTIFICATION DIVISION]

earn a [silver badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=silver)

---

#### Top(bar) Hat

[image: Top(bar) Hat]

earn rep for an answer or get an answer

proposed by [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304640/278094)

---

#### I’ll Handle It

[image: I’ll Handle It]

close, edit, reopen a question

---

#### Freehand Circle

[image: Freehand Circle]

earn the [Nice Answer badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer) on meta (Answer does not have to be from the winter bash, you only have to get the badge during the winter bash)

Also works on Meta Stack Exchange.

proposed by [Kevin Workman](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304830/278094)

---

#### Explorer

[image: Explorer]

accepted answer with no votes

---

#### Gonna Find Out

[image: Gonna Find Out]

vote 150 times

---

#### Member of The Hand

[image: Member of The Hand]

+3 post as new contributor, meta or main

---

#### Silencium

[image: Silencium]

question with no answers for a week

---

Comment: Just an observation, icons on Top(bar) hat are aligned wrongly. Achievement icon should be left of reviews. It is a [tag:bug]. Should I post a question and earn the same hat? ;-)

Comment: @NogShine I think so, [here's](http://bit.do/topbarhat) a fixed up version.

Comment: @NogShine at least someone didn't steal [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320032/358161) before me.

Comment: It's not clear whether **Silencium** can be earned for a closed question, specifically for one *closed as duplicate*.

Comment: Can someone clarify what "answer +3 a question with accepted answer" means? Does this mean that I need to answer a question that already has an accepted answer and get +3 on my answer? Or does my answer need to be accepted? Having a lot of trouble comprehending that...

Comment: @pushkin if you are asking about the "Pizza Hat" then your first assumption is correct. Post an answer to a question with an already accepted answer, and your answer get at least +3.

Comment: See also the published information at https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Also can the Rep Hunter not use Times New Roman next year? Perhaps what SE is always using for reps notifs? Or Maiandra GD?