# How close am I to earning the Gonna Find Out hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

Per the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319839/395288) to [Winter Bash 2018 Hat list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319838/winter-bash-2018-hat-list), it takes 150 votes to earn the Gonna Find Out hat.

I have voted more than 150 times on this site alone, so I assume that I must vote 150 times during Winter Bash to earn the hat. And if my assumption is correct...

**How do I find out how close I am to casting 150 votes during Winter Bash?**

I would look fabulous in this hat. ;-)

Comment: Identical question on [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377901/winter-bash-2018-hat-progres)

Comment: @SJade - It's OK for the question to be there, though it would be more generally useful (since it's applicable site-wide) if it were posted here. The answers there might assist you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there is no built in way to see the progress, you can see it by counting your votes in your profile.

There are two separate tabs, one for [upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=upvote) and one for [downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard?tab=votes&sort=downvote). Count the votes in each, starting from December 12 (2018) and you'll have your progress. (Each page contains 30 votes)

Note that since votes on deleted posts are not shown in those lists (even for 10k users), the count is only an estimation, and actual number might be higher.