# Where's my hat and how did I unlock it?

Tags: bug, winter-bash

I earned the *Retro Fan* hat on SE Meta. I can wear it, it appears in the hat part of my profile, but if I click on [the Winter Bash page](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/), I can't see it.

Where is it? I want to know what I did to unlock it, because that's kind of the point. Maybe it's a "shadow hat", that doesn't appear in the list until you unlock it, but what hasn't it appeared now(?).

I'm pretty sure I already had this problem in previous winter bashes, and I thought it'd been fixed by now.

Comment: Are you logged in to the WinterBash website?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319840/258356

Comment: @CinCout Oh! I thought I was automatically logged in, with the personal knitting zone and all. That's half of the problem, but I still don't know why I got the hat. "This is a secret hat". Maybe it's that way so people don't spoil secret hats?

Comment: It is not about spoiling the trigger. The answer I linked to already has the trigger mentioned for Retro Fan.

Comment: @CinCout What is it about then? Why do they need a special wiki page?

Comment: WinterBash is an year-end fun activity. The goal is to gather as many hats as possible, including finding out the secret hats along with their triggers. There is also a dedicated chatroom for the same: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86686/winter-bash-2018-edition

Answer (score 5):

Some things happen in some places at a different time to others.

Or in the words of Lisa Simpson

> It takes time to sugar-coat an answer

Basically, wait a few minutes for the change to be replicated to the different portals/databases.

SE has obfuscated the trigger for some hats by delaying the notification.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it takes a couple of minutes for the Winter Bash icon to notify you of hats you got even if you can already wear them. It should work after a little while.

Retro Fan is a [secret hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319838/winter-bash-2018-hat-list/319840#319840). It does not say how to get it when you put the hat on, but other users have figured this one out on the [winter bash hats page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319838/winter-bash-2018-hat-list/).