# Let's give top winter bashers some reputation!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, winter-bash

The people like [eLRuLL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/858913/elrull), [Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221571/eran), and [Panda](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/327561/panda) are *really* good at Winter Bash, with 30/[30 hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319838/winter-bash-2018-hat-list)! They deserve a reward! Hats aren't just for fun because getting a hat means that you did something good on the site, and if you get a lot that means you did some [*pretty spectacular things*](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48314748#48314748). Most of these things are contributions to the site(s), with the exception of a few fun ones. So I propose that **the *very* best Winter Bashers** get a little boost in reputation for being *amazing* participates in the community.

Winning places in one community would get you a bonus in that community, and winning the SE Network-Wide Leaderboard would give you your bouns in the community you earned the most amount of hats in (or all communities, but that seems like too much...)

So here we go:

```
#These numbers are just examples and reputation
#amounts could be changed and lowered as needed.
1st       = +100  
2nd       = +75  
3rd       = +60  
4th & 5th = +45
Top 10    = +25
Top 50    = +10 # These last ones could be too
Top 100   = +5  # much. Maybe remove them?...
----------------
20+ Hats  = +10
14+ Hats  = +6
 8+ Hats  = +4
```

Results would not stack up, so for example, 1st place does not mean you get a 2nd place bonus too.

Basically, lots of hats means you are *really* helpful to the community, so why not reward them with a tiny gift?

What do you think about this?

**Edit:**
[Mark Meyer suggested using badges instead of reputation, which is *so* much better than my idea.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321341/lets-give-top-winter-bashers-some-reputation/321345#321345)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think it would make the Winter Bash a little more fun if some swag was on the line, but I think reputation is the wrong way to express this.

Nicol Bolas [put it very well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367108/does-stack-overflow-reputation-have-any-value):

> Reputation is gratitude for providing good content.

Many of the actions for which you will be awarded a hat will also award reputation.

If you are in the top of the list, you have already picked up the reputation for those actions where it was warranted. To give *additional* reputation distorts the meaning of reputation and sets a precedent for giving rep to ancillary activities.

**Edit**

It *does* seem like a badge would be a nice reward. As the help [says here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-are-badges):

> Badges are little bits of digital flair that you earn for almost every kind of activity on Stack Overflow.

Badges are often awarded for ancillary activities and tend to represent a user's dedication to and exploration of the platform. The different levels badges corresponding to different levels of Winter Bash achievement would be a nice fit.

Comment: Ideas of what else? A badge?

Comment: Indeed. Reputation is the wrong reward. Some swag is a good option!

Comment: @EthanK yes, I think a badge is a nice idea and would fit well. Edited my answer.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yah, like a `Winter Basher` badge! If you want you could feature-request that. (why didn't I think of that?) I am accepting your answer!

Answer (score 9):

I disagree. Reputation is to show your expertise on a number of subjects on a specific site.

There are lots of users spending their free time to do reviews day in, day out, discuss site policy in chat, working on spam bots, etc, etc. They don't earn any reputation through that, so rewarding some users for a number of contributions in a short time frame seems unfair at least, and besides that unnecessary.

Comment: However, to get to those ranks on the leaderboard they would have to participate enough for that not to happen. This only could happen at lower ranks, not **the best** people.

Comment: For questions and answers they will earn reputation. That should be enough.

Comment: Fair, but these people are ***good*** (the ones in the top 20-ish). They deserve a bit of a reward.

Answer (score 0):

I like the basic idea of awarding reputation to the winners of winter bash, but 100 reputation for 1st place is *way* too high. I prefer the idea of basing it off the number of hats earned. Maybe something like:

```
10 hats = 5 reputation
20 hats = 10 reputation
30 hats = 15 reputation
all hats = 25 reputation
```

I think that because most winter bash hats encourage positive behavior, adding a small reward can increase participation in winter bash, and possibly the entire site.