# Why is Writing SE displayed as 'Writers' on Area 51, but not on the actual site?

Tags: support, area-51, site-name

When you [look at the Area 51 proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1623/writers) for [Writing StackExchange](https://writing.stackexchange.com/), it displays as *Writers*.  But, when you head to the actual site, it gives its name as *Writing*.  Is this because the name has been edited since proposal?  If so, why hasn't it been updated?

Comment: https://writers.stackexchange.com redirects to https://writing.stackexchange.com

Comment: But why the difference in name?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if you searched for *name change* on https://meta.writing.stackexchange, you would find [this](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1356/should-we-change-our-name) post as first result. Some people might see this as low-effort.

Comment: Not you.   I didn't @username you.  But thanks for not.

Comment: sorry I submitted my comment too early. I was pinged because I was the only one commenting on this post (except for you)

Comment: You can't delete questions if they have an upvoted or multiple answers.

Comment: More info on that [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222).

Comment: I really think other people will find future value in this, even though it has been heavily downvoted.

Comment: It's okay, everyone posts questions that get downvoted on meta. -4 really isn't that low, though.

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle [True ;)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321554/suggestions-for-winter-bash-2019/321563#321563)

Comment: If you really want to see a low scoring answer, look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes/33949#33949). The interesting thing is, the author only lost 168 reputation even though it scores under -200.

Comment: And [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required)'s an even lower-scoring question.

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle let's got to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1314/discussion-between-lordology-and-supa-mega-ducky-momo-da-waffle).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Area 51 is out of date. "Writers" changed to "Writing" [last year](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1463/34330).

Some of the time, the Area 51 proposal has been manually edited to reflect changes. You can see the revision history by clicking on "X years ago" under "edited" in the sidebar on Area 51 (if you don't see this, it probably hasn't ever been edited; it works just like posts). [Movies](https://area51.stackexchange.com/posts/3698/revisions) is a good example of a Area 51 proposal that was edited [after its expansion in name/scope](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/248/70064) to "Movies and TV". "Beer" was also edited to be ["Beer, Wine, and Spirits"](https://area51.stackexchange.com/posts/48905/revisions) two years ago.

For whatever reason, the moderation team hasn't yet updated the names of many sites. ["Community Building"](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/193) is still ["Moderators"](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52070/moderators) despite that change happing many years ago. "Psychology and Neuroscience" is still ["Cognitive Sciences"](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2149/cognitive-sciences). There's no "Veganism" in the listing for [Veganism & Vegetarianism](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94068/vegetarianism). The list goes on, even though there's really no good reason for these changes to the name not to be made. The reason is probably just that nobody thought to make these changes.

And then there's that site that's had several name changes: "Not Programming Related" to "Programmers" to now "Software Engineering". Area 51 still says ["Not Programming Related"](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352). Because of the drastic scope change, the description for the proposal was edited and there's a banner mentioning all these changes. Not mentioning all this history would make proposed questions like "What's good music for programmers to listen to?" seem way out of place. I think this is the exception rather than the rule.

The Stack Overflow in <Language> proposals are also exceptions, since they are listed with an English name and a bilingual description in Area 51, something that wouldn't be good on the actual site.

Comment: Have any of the proposed sites on Area 51 been synchronized with the name of the site later? If not, then it seems likely that this hasn't been done because it isn't *expected*. That the Area 51 name refers to the proposed site, not the current beta or launched site.

Comment: @NicolBolas The names on Area 51 refer to the site's name while it was still being defined. I've never seen it updated after a site graduated. Just as an example, Software Engineering graduated, but [it's still shown as Not Programming Related](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related) on area 51.

Comment: @SupaM: That's the point I'm getting at. Saying "Area 51 is out of date" assumes that A51 is *supposed* to be kept "up to date" with the current site's name. Similarly, "hasn't yet updated" implies that the intent is that it will be updated. I'm asking if there is a reason for this implication, if there was a statement or expectation for them to match which isn't being met currently. Contrast that with MSOGA's answer, who simply states that they are "different entities" and thus are not *supposed* to be kept "up to date".

Comment: @NicolBolas People searching for a site on Area 51 shouldn't have to know the old name of the site to search for it. Likewise, it's confusing to click on a link to one site and be taken to a site with a different name on Area 51 (even though they are the same site). This, combined with the fact that I can't really make rhyme or reason out of which ones get updated and which don't lead me to believe that there *isn't* much rhyme or reason and that they just forgot to update some of the pages.