# Should we award a badge to people who document the tags they create?

Tags: discussion, badge-request

Similar to the `Curious`, `Inquisitive` and `Socratic` badges which reward a particular good behaviour (asking nice questions), the idea is to encourage people to document the tags they create rather than leaving that task to our *very few* `Research Assistant`s (just [above 300](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1656/research-assistant) of them on Stack Overflow at time of writing).

Comment: There always has been a problem with tag wiki's being plagiarized. The badge might increase that. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313486/lets-stop-tag-wiki-plagiarism

Comment: @rene Thank you for bringing that up. Assuming that this problem can somehow be either fixed or mitigated in the future, do you reckon this may still be something to consider?

Comment: Do we need to reward them with more than the +2 rep for each tag wiki or excerpt update?

Comment: @fbueckert One could argue the same thing for many other badges out there. Do we need to award a `Nice Answer` (and up) badge to someone who already got their _X_ many +10 rep? To me a badge also works as a mean to let other people know about the kind of behaviour Stack Exchange value (and encourage people to do the same). To answer your question: I'd say yes. Considering that tags need some attention, this could be a nice way IMHO.

Comment: Maybe we need to try this first: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321575/158100 so we can test its (side-)effects in a controlled manner.

Comment: @rene Sounds good.

Comment: @rene That reasons a punishment for plagiarized tag wikis, and not removing (or not giving) reward for all creators of the tag wikis.

Comment: @fbueckert It is a matter of taste, what is the worth of which activity. Similar things (creating main site posts) pay typically much better, while creating tag wikis is harder (in theory).

Comment: @peterh it doesn't reason that at all unless you have that mindset which is something I don't (want to) control.

Comment: I think you're looking at the problem incorrectly here. I'd bet a huge portion of our users simply don't even know that tag wikis exist because they never look at them or the excerpt. A better solution would be somehow surfacing this information in a more visible way. If people know they exist and see them more, people will be more willing to curate them. Adding another badge will do literally nothing here.

Comment: @animuson I'd certainly agree that there are UX/UI opportunities to improve things and you're perhaps right in that these should be prioritised first. However do you have any data to suggest that a badge will simply make no difference at all? As mentioned a badge can be seen as a mean to reward good behaviour (and promote it). There are badges for good questions & answers and for people bothering with keeping posts relevant and alive. In comparison, tags look like a second-class citizen.