# My suggestion for Winter Bash 2019 was deleted for no reasons

Tags: discussion, support, meta, moderation, winter-bash

Not a long time ago, there was an idea to create the "Reinstate Monica" hat. I've put that into action. After an hour of photoshopping, I got the result.

[image]

[And I posted it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKQwl.jpg), with the title "Reinstate Monica hat", and nothing more.

This was not:

> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - barely more than a link to an external site
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

It wasn't. Although, later in the day, it was deleted by moderator [Tinkeringbell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/369802/tinkeringbell).

No comments. No suggestions. No reasons.

Why?

Comment: If you're asking a question here, can you make it explicit? As of now, this looks like a rant, which doesn't really support discussion.

Comment: Did you miss where that moderator also locked the post and explained why they did both things? See [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321554/suggestions-for-winter-bash-2019#comment1125076_321554).

Comment: No comments, no suggestions, no reasons,... and *no sense of humor*

Comment: And my answer (112 upvotes)? That too was deleted. Along with several other answer-hats.

Comment: I have now changed my username to include Reinstate Monica **and** I changed my profile image to use your hat. Thank you! And ironically, the deletion of other answers now puts an actual genuine original pre-crisis Monica answer at the top of the list. In any case, I currently plan to skip any StackExchange-offered hats this year as my Reinstate Monica hat will do just fine. Unless Monica is reinstated, of course.

Comment: @manassehkatz-ReinstateMonica Haha thanks :)

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Yeah, I missed this part. But he did it only after I posted my answer, so it seems he's not interested in reinstating Monica.

Comment: As the original poster of the question, I am not very happy with the censoring policy in this case. There was a really rude suggestion (not in the ones mentioned by the OP or @Mari-LouA) but even in this case I think it is better to argue that it is bad advised (I did this in the comments) and to downvote.

Comment: @Scott Seidman: Well, [we *hate* fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Comment: Feel free to not participate (lol)

Comment: @VerNicksaysReinstateMonica can you make one that says GoFundMonica?

Comment: @DeNovosupportsGoFundMonica Yeah, will be ready in 10-20 minutes

Comment: @DeNovosupportsGoFundMonica [Here you go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8wq4.png)

Comment: I just gimped my avatar to wear that hat in a winterbash style.

Comment: @jknappen-ReinstateMonica Nice :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Tinkeringbell already explained why in [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321554/suggestions-for-winter-bash-2019#comment1125076_321554) under the question which they also locked:

> We have deleted several (sometimes rude/passive aggressive) attempts
>   at dragging current events into an event that's supposed to be all
>   about fun. While we understand everyone's frustration, winter bash
>   suggestions are not the place to fight this fight, and ruin fun for
>   other users. We're locking this question for a while to give it some
>   time to cool down, and hopefully any new suggestions posted after that
>   will be more constructive. – Tinkeringbell ↵♦ 12 hours ago

When a moderator locks a post they almost always leave some kind of reason why. Often they do this when many answers have to be removed as well. In the future, it would probably be a helpful first step to check under the question for comments that might explain things.

Comment: "While we understand everyone's frustration, winter bash suggestions are not the place to fight this fight, and ruin fun for other users." — yeah, we ruin fun for other users, who don't have fun here at all.

Comment: Being denied my **meh!** cap ruined the fun for me.