# Can the community satisfy Sparky's demands before the earth is destroyed? [A novel Winter Bash idea]

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, fun, humor

*Out of character*:  This is a *Winter Bash* idea motivated by comments such as:

> As an aside, I would love to hear suggestions from people that **have nothing to do with hats**. This was the 8th year we've done the same thing with different triggers and to be honest, I turned them off this year because I've gotten kind of bored with the idea. ...
>   <sub>[animuson ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321554/suggestions-for-winter-bash-2019/321862#comment1052792_321554), 2019</sub>

Here is a suggestion which *has nothing to do with hats*.  Stack Exchange as a whole is now part of an ***interactive story*** (see below): comply to Sparky's demands, or earth is destroyed.

Sparky comes along each winter (say) with specific demands [replacing hat triggers], and will destroy earth if they are not met. Users of Stack Exchange need to *work together* (not individually, like for hats) to save earth.  If Sparky leaves without destroying earth, Stack Exchange (as a whole) wins.

**Question**: Can the community satisfy Sparky's demands before the earth is destroyed?

It's indented for *fun* and to foster a team spirit (think: "yay! we joined forces and defeated Sparky!").  It also aims to have fresh and imaginative one-off "triggers" (many people complained about the repetitive hat triggers), with Sparky coming back sporadically to make alien demands.

(May I remind you of [unicoins](/questions/tagged/unicoins), [time-travel-mode](/questions/tagged/time-travel-mode), [isUserAGoat()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375357/proper-use-cases-for-android-usermanager-isuseragoat), [W](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/74383/91818), [HTML+regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), etc.?)

<sub>(PS: I thought of this before *The Mess* got messier.  Please don't downvote because of *The Mess++*.)</sub>

---

#### ? (non-story version)

For those who don't like stories...  Sparky is a fictional entity who makes sporadic unorthodox "demands" (i.e., sets peculiar challenges for the community).  The one I thought up is:

> - Ask three questions by *three different users* on *three different sites*.
> - The title needs to contain the word "hippopotamus".
> - Each needs to reach the *Hot Network Questions* list.
> - This has to be done in *January 2020*.

The demands will change as the story progresses.  Basically, we do what Sparky says and "we win" (for now), and the interactive story continues.  Otherwise "we lose" (perhaps Sparky destroys earth).

It's intended to become part of an ongoing interactive story, with other quirky challenges.  The community is part of the story.

(*Relevant search*: [`hippopotamus is:question created:01-2020`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=hippopotamus%20is%3Aquestion%20created%3A01-2020).)

---

### ?  (story version)

***Captain!***  We've received a message from a "being" (for lack of a better word); we've been calling it ***Sparky***.  We believe we captured an image of Sparky below:

> [image: Sparky appears as a yellow/orange squiggle with a purple outline; Sparky has eyes, a mouth, and some long wavy strands of hair; Sparky appears emotionless; Sparky's background contains multiple blue spots.]

Sparky's language is unlike that on earth (it sounds something like dolphins communicating), but ***we believe we have translated a threatening message***:

> Greetings Farthlings!
>
> [muffled sounds] ... I need to flick the switch on the side?  ...  Is it not recording?  ...  [redacted]  ...
>
> ***Greetings Farthlings!!***
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> [approx. 30 seconds pass]
>
> I greet you with awkward silence, as is customary in our culture.  Please do so in kind.
>
> I am informed you will perceive me as a kind of squiggle.  Understand, I come from a *universe* which *intersects* yours.  I too am from Farth, but in my *dimension*.  Understand, ***I am mighty!!***  *Do not call me unbefitting nicknames like "zip" or "ziggy"*.  I shall be properly addressed as *Admiral Flippy Floppy* [*ed*: our best translation].
>
> I find your planet quirky.  I enjoy watching you squirm like how you enjoy watching "reality TV".
>
> Of all that your species has "achieved" [muffled snickering], I'm fond of the word "hippopotamus".  I thus assign you a task:
>
> > **To save Farth (for now)...** get the word "hippopotamus" thrice to the *Hot Network Questions* page.  More specifically:
> >
> > - Ask three questions by *three different users* on *three different sites*.
> > - The title needs to contain the word "hippopotamus".
> > - Each needs to reach the *Hot Network Questions* list.
> > - This has to be done in *January 2020*.
>
> Do this or I'll... umm... oh, there's so many ways I could destroy Farth, how do I decide?  Okay, I'll raise temperatures on your planet by 2 degrees.  [muffled sounds]  What do you mean they're already doing that themselves?  Wow, these humans are [unintelligible].  ***Do this or I'll push Farth into the Sun!***  [*ed*: at this point, Sparky played a sound effect]  How's that?  Okay, good.  I'll be back at the end of January to destroy Farth, or not.
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> [approx. 30 seconds pass]
>
> *Admiral Flippy Floppy* out.

Captain, we don't really know if Sparky can destroy earth.  We have not seen any being like this before.  Maybe we should do what Sparky says, just in case.

Comment: I don't understand anything you're saying here. Can you please make it clearer?

Comment: Wait. Is this a strange hat suggestion?

Comment: I appreciate the creativity here, but I am so, so confused...

Comment: I think you should reconsider the example challenge. This will lead to 10,000 different questions all playing off of “hippopotamus” all across the network, as people have no real means of coordination here (which is a challenge generally for your team-based idea, outside of no individual motivators).

Comment: Perhaps, although I don't predict a flood of hippopotamus-related questions, and it's only a once-off challenge.  (I'm expecting Biology.SE, WorldBuilding.SE, and Chess.SE might get one or two, and maybe some of the language sites.)  In any case, it looks like the idea is not even going to even be given a chance.  [It would be nice to discuss, but the question has been closed...]

Comment: (I still believe in you, Sparky.  Destroy those pesky humans!)

Comment: I agree that this is a bad idea. I have no idea why so many people are confused by it, though. It's a very clear, specific suggestion, with a long example

Comment: Not sure about Hippos - OTOH Whales might work as then we would be collectively trying to "Save the Whales"...

Comment: I'm a bit sad this didn't happen.  Poor sparky.  (:

Answer (score 12):

I do not like the suggestion as described because participation in the interactive story involves the contents of questions and answers. While hats and badges may alter behavior, the intention is to increase desired behavior on the network without altering the content. This suggestion is directed at the content of posts. Posts should be real questions users encounter in their own experience, with answers solving an actual problem. This type of game would encourage less relevant questions (and answers).

Comment: Thanks!  So... is it just the particular goal?  The goal could be easily changed—I wanted something quirky and fun at the time.  Anything beyond this?