# Is there any badge for editing a downvoted answer which later receives upvotes?

Tags: support, edits, badges

I saw an​ answer, but even though it was correctly pointing OP's mistake, the answer read as the poster was trying to get some clarification from the OP; and the answer was too short. The answer got downvoted.

Original answer:

> Are you using in-memory or database authentication? I don't see any. Refer this link for step by step guide.

I would modify it as follows:

> In your configuration you are missing authentication part that is why your authentication is getting failed.
>
> You can use configure authentication by auth-config1
>
> ```
> bla bla bla
> ```
>
> Or
>
> You can use configure authentication by auth-config2
>
> ```
> bla bla bla
> ```
>
> For step by step guide refer this link

I don't see anything great for writing my own answer instead of editing the correct answer.

Now my question: if that answer gets accepted or gets upvotes in future (after getting edited), is there any badge rewarding the person who edited it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges)

Answer (score 10):

No, there's no such a badge. Editing answers will count towards the Strunk and White/Copy Editor badges, though.

**But** there was a hat in [2018's Winter Bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319840/398063) that had a similar trigger:

> #### Clean-Up Duty<sup>1</sup>
>
> [image: Clean-Up Duty]
>
> Edit 5 questions that later get upvoted.
>
> Trigger confirmed by Catija [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48363606#48363606).

Comment: The picture says it all :-D ...