# Why no Solstice hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

There appears to be no Solstice hat this year (unless it's super secret). I haven't seen anyone with a Solstice hat, and it's not on the [Winter Bash 2018 Hat list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319838/winter-bash-2018-hat-list).

Where in the World hats that looked like Solstice hats appeared in the [2016 hat list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271/winter-bash-2016-all-hats/288284#288284), and they were fantastic!

[image: Sun Solstice hat]
[image: Moon Solstice hat]

Why not this year? Was it for lack of mention on [Suggestions for Winter Bash 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305500/suggestions-for-winter-bash-2018)? Some other reason?

Comment: It is boring to have hats with the same trigger every year; I guess that the designers chose to make the hats different, and less predictable. A secret hat is not a secret hat if you know you can earn one by doing X.

Comment: @hat When writing a hat question, I will pay heed to the comment of a user named hat ;-)

Comment: Naa...names aren't everything. : )

Comment: @hat But they add to the fun, and that's what it's all about!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be because of one or more of the following reasons:

1. The team didn't like feel like adding one.
2. They didn't want to repeat hats with similar triggers year-after-year.
3. They thought it would be too easy a trigger for a secret hat.
4. They thought it was pointless because Solstice is just overrated.
5. It wasn't mentioned on "Suggestions for Winter Bash 2018" as pointed out by you in the question.
6. A completely different reason I can't even guess.

Maybe in the post they will do after the Winter Bash ends, one in which they reveal all the secret hats, they might reveal the reason for not including a Solstice hat this year. Until then, all we can do is guess!

You should consider proposing it for WB 2019 in case you want the hat to appear next year.

Comment: I think I will propose another Solstice hat. The Solstice is the reason for the winter (or summer) season!

Answer (score 10):

It seems that there’s indeed no Solstice hat this year, since they were [awarded on Dec 21 or Dec 22](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304805/327561) in past years.

A reasonable guess would be that secret hats requiring to vote/ post on a specific date are getting old and they’re way too easy to get. So, they’ve cut down on the number of such hats this year.

It’s worth noting that it’s possible there will be a vote/ post hat on Christmas Day, since there’s been one every year from 2012 to 2017, except for 2014.

Comment: We already have an Xmas hat, Gonna Find Out, so maybe you're right about no more hats awarded on specific days.